# Unable read data from .events file in c++

Tags: c++

I have created a powershell script to create abc.events file and added hello word to it through powershell.

But when I used ifstream to get line,it's coming as some unicode ybh

```
C++ code is like 
Std:ifstream ifs;
ifs.open("c:/abc.events")
String line;
getline(ifs,line)
```

Line should have hello but it's coming as some wildchar ybh...
How to get exact string from .events file in c++

Comment: What is the exact contents of this file? Can you please give a short example of the contents of the file, taken from the beginning? How was the file created? How did you write to it? *What* Did you write to it?

Comment: Did you verify with a hex editor that the file content is what you expect? Is it plain ASCII or is it Unicode?

Comment: Also please take some time to read or refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and how to [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: That's not valid C++ (unless you use another library providing non-standard namespace and classes) – apart from, if that's a unicode file, have you considered [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? Is 0xef 0xbb 0xbf for UTF-8, which might be mapped to special characters in another encoding that might be in use on your system.